# How to change the Bulk actions order int the Woocommerce orders list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Good-evening i would like to ask if the is a way to change (or replace) the order in which the drop-down list actions from the bulk actions are shown.
i include an image from what i like to accomplish.

[image: The order wanted]

Thank you in advance

Comment: I just want to change the order of these choices. but i ll try to change the language

Comment: by browser tools you mean the google browser developer tools? and where exactly can i see this?